# Use express and hapijs together

Tags: node.js, http, express, hapi.js

We have a somewhat big nodejs app using express. We started experimenting with hapijs on smaller services and kind of like it more than express. So we'd like to migrate the express app to hapijs. But since the app is already big, and we don't want to do a complete rewrite at once, but rewrite it step by step, so we can do it in more time. Is there any way to use express and hapijs within the same nodejs process and do the routing between those to by routes?

Comment: Rather than same process which would be tricky, it'd be easier to throw up a reverse proxy in front of the two separate processes and transition bit by bit.

Comment: I can expand in an answer if that sounds like an interesting plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through on this link:
[Hecks](https://github.com/devinivy/hecks)

It will show you how to mount your express app onto your hapi server.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options to do it:

1. You can run those in two separate servers under a HAProxy and decide which server will answer by the route.
2. You can run 2 separate servers where Hapi will be in charge on all the routes once the route is not found it will proxy the request to express.

Option 1 will have better performance and help you in the future when you need to scale.